# Python: how to retrieve and plot the unmasked part of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, mask

I have the following 2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([[4,1,1,2],[1,1,9,6],[1,2,8,4],[1,11,17,8]])
```

which I want to mask so to ignore the values that are `<2`:

```
m = np.ma.masked_where(y<2, y)
```

The plot is this:

```
plt.imshow(m,interpolation='nearest',origin='lower')
```

[image]

Now, let's say I want to ignore the mask, and focus on the remainder. **How can I extract the areas where `y>2`, assign them `1`, and plot them together with the masked areas?**

The result is something similar to the above plot, only that the `y>2` squares have value 1 and are plotted with the same color.

Comment: Isn't that basically the mask you already have, so  `plt.imshow(m.mask)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `np.where` and the boolean mask you already created

`m2 = np.where(m.mask, 1, y)`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments above, this problem can be solved by calling

```
import numpy.ma as ma
mask=ma.getmask(m) 
im=plt.imshow(mask,origin='lower') #equivalent to plt.imshow(m.mask,origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(im)
```

which produces

[image]

Then, if one wants to assign `1` to the unmasked areas:

```
im2=numpy.logical_not(mask)
im3=plt.imshow(im2,origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(im3)
```

which yields

[image]

Now the masked areas have value `0`, and the unmasked areas have value `1`.